# Show percentage values in stacked bar in order

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, stacked-chart

How can I sort the series in descending order in each category group and show them up in a single bar for each group?
This is how the project and report looks like:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Revert back to the stacked bar, in which category groups does not contain the percentage field.

In the category groups, click the litte arrow at the end of the CollectionTime series.  Choose Category Group Properties.  In that dialog, select Sorting in the left pane, then set your sort expression to equal Percentage_In_ThisPeriod.  That should order your CollectionTimes based on the Percentage field.